# how to change dynamically a form after a search CodenameOne

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

i want to know how to dynamically change a form after a search, i have:

```
 Form hi = new Form("Soggetti");
        BoxLayout b=new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        TableLayout ttt=new TableLayout(10,1);
        int ttt_height=20;
        ttt.setDefaultRowHeight(ttt_height);
        ttt.setDefaultColumnWidth(100);
        hi.setLayout(ttt);
MultiButton bbb=new MultiButton();
        bbb.setTextLine1("Soggetto 1");
        bbb.setTextLine2("Dettagli ");
        bbb.setIcon(i);
        bbb.setEmblem(s);

        MultiButton bbb2=new MultiButton();
        bbb2.setTextLine1("Soggetto 1");
        bbb2.setTextLine2("Dettagli ");
        bbb2.setIcon(i);
        bbb2.setEmblem(s);
        MultiButton bbb3=new MultiButton();
        bbb3.setTextLine1("Soggetto 1");
        bbb3.setTextLine2("Dettagli ");
        bbb3.setIcon(i);
        bbb3.setEmblem(s);

bbb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                int p=1;
                p++;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //    bbb3.setVisible(true);
                hi.removeAll();
                //hi = new Form("Soggetti");

                BoxLayout b=new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

                TableLayout ttt=new TableLayout(10,1);
                int ttt_height=5;
                ttt.setDefaultRowHeight(ttt_height);
                ttt.setDefaultColumnWidth(100);
                hi.setLayout(ttt);
                //ci ricreiamo i i bottoni precedenti
                hi.addComponent(bbb);
                hi.addComponent(bbb2);

              ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> alhm= Ricerca("");
              Label contatto=null;
              for(int j=0;j<alhm.size();j++){
                  LinkedHashMap s=alhm.get(j);
                  String nome=(String) s.get("firstName");
                    String cognome=(String) s.get("lastName");
                    String numero =(String) s.get("numero");
                    contatto=new Label(nome+" "+cognome+" "+numero);

                     Double id= (Double) s.get("id");
                  hi.addComponent(contatto);
                }

              hi.addComponent(bbb3);

            //    SchermataRubrica sr=new SchermataRubrica();
            //    sr.getSchermata();
              hi.show();
            }

        });

        hi.addComponent(bbb);
        hi.addComponent(bbb2);
        hi.addComponent(bbb3);

        hi.addCommand(Schermata1);
        hi.addCommand(Schermata2);
        hi.addCommand(Schermata3);

        hi.show();
```

when the multibutton bbb2 is clicked i want to show the result below that multibutton but instead it messed all up...probably i'm missing something at a logic level...
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `hi.show()` in the results with a `hi.revalidate()`.

I would probably not use TableLayout for search results and would opt for `BoxLayout`. See our in-place search here, its probably not exactly what you need but should give you a hint: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-4.html

You can also animate the removal/addition of components rather nicely with `animateUnlayout` and `animateLayout`.

Comment: Thanks Shai, i will try, i want to thank you for all the answer and tips you are giving me...you arr awesome